# Lebesgue measure of $\mu(A):=\int_A e^{-x} d \lambda(x)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Consider the measurable space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $\lambda)$, where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure restricted to it. For $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, let
$$
\mu(A):=\int_A e^{-x} d \lambda(x) .
$$
My question is about how to compute the measure of the set (A) when it takes the form of intervals, such as $\mu([0, \infty])$ or $\mu(\mathbb{R})$, where in the first case there are only positive values and in the second, both positive and negative values.

I'm trying to apply the Lebesgue measure definition to this specific case:
\begin{equation*}
 \lambda(A):=\operatorname{inf}\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} v\left(I_n\right) ; A \subseteq \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_n: n \in \mathbb{N}, I_n \in \mathcal{I}^N,\right\}
\end{equation*}
where $\mathcal{I}^N$ is the family of bounded intervals, and $v(I_n)$ represents the lengths of the intervals, but i can't get any satisfactory reuslts. In my example, it's one dimension, hence $n=1$.

The integration is with respect to the variable $\lambda(x)$ over the chosen set $A$, when it takes the form $[0, \infty]$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

First Edition:

I think a possible solution is to take intervals as follows and multiply it by exponential
$$
\begin{gathered}
\lambda([b, \infty))=\lambda([b, b+1) \cup[b+1, b+2) \ldots)=\lambda\left(\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}[b+k, b+k+1)\right)= \\
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \lambda([b+k, b+k+1))=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 1=\infty
\end{gathered}
$$
And the last, multiply by the exponential
\begin{equation}
   -e^{-x}\cdot\lambda([b, \infty))=   -e^{-x}\cdot\lambda([0, \infty))=-e^{-x}\cdot\infty
\end{equation}
But I’m not sure if the interval also applies to the exponential or not. I think so

Comment: If $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, and you may use the known properties of that, then $\mu(A)=\int_A e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d} x$, which would be the "classical" Lebesgue integral. Or do you want to derive the above from first principles?

Comment: Note that in your last sentence: $\lambda(x)$ is not a variable - $x$ is the variable, $\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)$ is the measure that is used in the integration.

Comment: That detail you have written is important, I had not interpreted it correctly. I'm writing my attempt

Comment: Small note: $[0,\infty]$ is *not* a subset of $\mathbb R$ so on that set the measure is not defined (maybe you had $[0,\infty)$ in mind). Further $e^{-x}$ is a positive function and $-e^{-x}$ is an antiderivative of it. You can make use of that.

Comment: Hint: if $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure then $\int_{[a,b]}e^{-x}d\lambda=F(b)-F(a)$ if $[a,b]\subseteq\mathbb R$ and $F$ is an antiderivative of $e^{-x}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answers I have already understood that the lebesgue integral is equal to the Riemann integral in this specific case, and therefore the result is a typical analysis exercise.